# Dark forces and galactic filaments

Tags: dark-matter

Could it be that dark energy = momentum of hydrogen in galactic filaments, and dark matter the mass of the galactic filaments?

Comment: You need to qualify this statement, if you intend people to take it seriously. How can momentum make space-time expand in the same way as dark energy?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Dark energy appears to be the tendency of space-time to expand.  Momentum doesn't cause space-time to expand. So while we don't understand dark energy well, its not just "ordinary energy" in any form.

Dark matter cannot be the baryonic matter in filaments. The process of forming baryonic matter can't produce enough to account for the mass in the universe, and we know (from observations of galaxy rotation) that dark matter exists in a halo around galaxies, not in filaments. So unless our models of matter formation are very wrong, dark matter is probably some as-yet-undiscovered massive particle.